# React how to make table container that beautiful dnd works

Tags: reactjs, react-table, react-beautiful-dnd

I have made a table with beautiful-dnd components so i can reorder rows
but since i have large amount of data, i want to make a table container so I can have a scrollable fixed size table
but if i add "react-table-container", drag and drop no longer works.

Can anyone help me how to make a container that is draggable

```
export default function DataTable({ data, title }) {
  const columns = useMemo(() => COLUMNS, []);
  const {
    getTableProps,
    getTableBodyProps,
    headerGroups,
    rows,
    prepareRow,
  } = useTable(
    {
      columns,
      data,
    },
    useSortBy
  );
  return (
    <>
      <div className="title">{title} </div>

  <DragDropContext
    onDragEnd={(param) => {
      if (!param.destination) {
        return;
      }
      const srcIdx = param.source.index;
      const desIdx = param.destination.index;
      rows.splice(desIdx, 0, rows.splice(srcIdx, 1)[0]);
    }}
  >
    <ReactTableContainer width="auto" height="800px">
      <Droppable droppableId="droppable">
        {(provided, snapshot) => (
          <table
            ref={provided.innerRef}
            id="players"
            {...getTableProps()}
            style={{ width: 1000, height: 500 }}
          >
            <thead>
              {headerGroups.map((headerGroup) => (
                <tr {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()}>
                  {headerGroup.headers.map((column) => (
                    <th
                      {...column.getHeaderProps(
                        column.getSortByToggleProps()
                      )}
                    >
                      {column.render("Header")}
                      <span className="sort-icon">
                        {column.isSorted ? (
                          column.isSortedDesc ? (
                            <SortUpIcon />
                          ) : (
                            <SortDownIcon />
                          )
                        ) : (
                          ""
                        )}
                      </span>
                      <div className="filter">
                        {column.canFilter ? column.render("Filter") : null}
                      </div>
                    </th>
                  ))}
                </tr>
              ))}
            </thead>
            <tbody {...getTableBodyProps()}>
              {rows.map((row, i) => {
                prepareRow(row);
                return (
                  <Draggable
                    key={row.id}
                    draggableId={row.id}
                    index={i}
                    className="draggableRow"
                  >
                    {(provided, snapshot) => (
                      <tr
                        ref={provided.innerRef}
                        {...provided.draggableProps}
                        {...provided.dragHandleProps}
                        {...row.getRowProps()}
                        style={{
                          ...provided.draggableProps.style,
                          boxShadow: snapshot.isDragging
                            ? "0 0 .4rem #666"
                            : "none",
                        }}
                      >
                        {row.cells.map((cell) => {
                          return (
                            <td {...cell.getCellProps()}>
                              {cell.render("Cell")}
                            </td>
                          );
                        })}
                      </tr>
                    )}
                  </Draggable>
                );
              })}
              {provided.placeholder}
            </tbody>
          </table>
        )}
      </Droppable>
    </ReactTableContainer>
  </DragDropContext>
</>
```

);
}

Answer (score 1):

Add `{...provided.droppableProps}` under `ref={provided.innerRef}`

```js
<table
   ref={provided.innerRef}
   id="players"
   {...provided.droppableProps}
   {...getTableProps()}
   style={{ width: 1000, height: 500 }}
>
```

Comment: the code i have is working draggable table i just wanna add table container

Comment: Can you create codesandbox or codepen with your code, so I could jump in?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-dew-cwjsc?file=/src/DataTable.js

Here's the link I imported data from my own data file

Comment: It's DataTable file that i'm having trouble on

Comment: When I run your code sandbox it gives me a lot of errors regarding missing dependencies, and even when I install them it is acting up, can you check it? Does it work ok for you?

Comment: ye it seems like mine doesn't work too... i haven't used snadbox before so i don'treally know how to use it